# Side-by-side algorithms in latex

Tags: algorithm, latex, algorithm2e

I am using "elsarticle" class and need to place two algorithms side by side. I am using minipage fucntion to do this but algorithms are not generated exactly side by side (a picture is attached for your reference). A working latex code is given as:

```
documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]             
%   \caption{(X,Y)-only  co-Z addition with update     ($ZADDU_{(X,Y)}$)}  
    \caption{ $ZADDU_{(X,Y)}$}          
    
    \label{alg1}   
    %\begin{multicols}{2}                       % and a label for \ref{} commands 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \Require{ $R_1 = (X_1, Y_1, Z )$ and $R_2 = (X_2, Y_2, Z)$ }
    \Ensure {$(R_3, R_1)\mspace{5mu} = \mspace{5mu}ZADDU_{(X,Y)}(R_1, R_2)$ $\mspace{15mu}$where $R_3= R_1 + R_2=
(X_3, Y_3, Z_3)$ and $R_1 = (\lambda^2{X_1}, \lambda^3 {Y_1}, Z_3)$  with $Z_3=\lambda Z$ for some $\lambda\neq0$}\\
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase A:}}
%   $z := 0, R_1 := x$\;
%   $R_2 := u_2$\; 
%   
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase B:}}
$B=(X_1-X_2)^2$; 
    $E_1 =X_1 U; E_2 = X_2 U$; $C =(Y_1 - Y_2)^2$\\
      $D =Y_1 (E_1 - E_2)$; $X_3=C - E_1 - E_2$; 
      $Y_3=(Y_1 - Y_2)(E_1 - X_3 ) - D$;\\
       ${X_1}=  E_1$; ${Y_1} = D$; 
     $R_3=(X_3, Y_3)$, $R_3=(X_1, Y_1)$\\
    \Return{($R_3,R_1$)}\;
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
%        \caption{(X,Y)-only  conjugate co-Z addition ($ZADDC_{(X,Y)}$)}              
    \caption{$ZADDC_{(X,Y)}$}          
    % give the algorithm a caption
    \label{alg1}   
    %\begin{multicols}{2}                       % and a label for \ref{} commands 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \Require{ $R_1 = (X_1, Y_1, Z )$ and $R_2 = (X_2, Y_2, Z)$ }
    \Ensure {$(R_3, \overline R_3)\mspace{5mu} = \mspace{5mu}ZADDC_{(X,Y)}(R_1, R_2)$$\mspace{10mu}$where $R_3= R_1 + R_2=
(X_3, Y_3, Z_3)$ and $\overline R_3 =R_1 - R_2= (\overline{X_3},\overline {Y_3}, Z_3)$ }\\
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase A:}}
%   $z := 0, R_1 := x$\;
%   $R_2 := u_2$\; 
%   
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase B:}}
$B=(X_1-X_2)^2$;  
    $E_1 =X_1 U; E_2 = X_2 U$; $C =(Y_1 - Y_2)^2$;\\
      $D =Y_1 (E_1 - E_2)$; $X_3=C - V_1 - V_2$;
      $Y_3=(Y_1 - Y_2)(E_1 - X_3 ) - D$; \\
     $\overline{C} = (Y1 + Y2)^2$;  $\overline{X_3}=  \overline{C} - E_1 - E_2$; $\overline{Y_3} = (Y_1 + Y_2)(E_1 - \overline{X_3} ) - D$;\\
    
    \Return{($R_3,\overline R_3$)}\;
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An output picture is attached, any help to align these algorithms side by side would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: From the usage summary for [tag:latex], which you correctly used for this question: "LaTeX questions are often a better fit for the sister site [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com)." You should probably follow that advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- missing `\` in front of `documentclass`
- incompatible package. Your document will produce the error

  ```
  Command \listofalgorithms already defined. ...s}{\listof{algorithm}{\listalgorithmname}}
  ```

  You should never ignore error messages. After an error latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output
- you are placing two minipages with `.5\textwidth` each besides each other. This will fill the entire line leaving no space for all the additional spaces added by your unescaped line endings. Either make your minipages smaller or add `%` at the end of lines so they don't act like spaces
- use unique labels for your algorithms
- the `hyperref` package should be loaded as one of the last packages. Don't load it directly at the start of your preamble
- and just from your picture I would guess that in your real document you are missing an empty line before the minipages

```
\documentclass[3p]{elsarticle}

%\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]             
%   \caption{(X,Y)-only  co-Z addition with update     ($ZADDU_{(X,Y)}$)}  
    \caption{ $ZADDU_{(X,Y)}$}          
    
    \label{alg1}   
    %\begin{multicols}{2}                       % and a label for \ref{} commands 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \Require{ $R_1 = (X_1, Y_1, Z )$ and $R_2 = (X_2, Y_2, Z)$ }
    \Ensure {$(R_3, R_1)\mspace{5mu} = \mspace{5mu}ZADDU_{(X,Y)}(R_1, R_2)$ $\mspace{15mu}$where $R_3= R_1 + R_2=
(X_3, Y_3, Z_3)$ and $R_1 = (\lambda^2{X_1}, \lambda^3 {Y_1}, Z_3)$  with $Z_3=\lambda Z$ for some $\lambda\neq0$}\\
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase A:}}
%   $z := 0, R_1 := x$\;
%   $R_2 := u_2$\; 
%   
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase B:}}
$B=(X_1-X_2)^2$; 
    $E_1 =X_1 U; E_2 = X_2 U$; $C =(Y_1 - Y_2)^2$\\
      $D =Y_1 (E_1 - E_2)$; $X_3=C - E_1 - E_2$; 
      $Y_3=(Y_1 - Y_2)(E_1 - X_3 ) - D$;\\
       ${X_1}=  E_1$; ${Y_1} = D$; 
     $R_3=(X_3, Y_3)$, $R_3=(X_1, Y_1)$\\
    \Return{($R_3,R_1$)}\;
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
%\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
%        \caption{(X,Y)-only  conjugate co-Z addition ($ZADDC_{(X,Y)}$)}              
    \caption{$ZADDC_{(X,Y)}$}          
    % give the algorithm a caption
    \label{alg2}   
    %\begin{multicols}{2}                       % and a label for \ref{} commands 
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \Require{ $R_1 = (X_1, Y_1, Z )$ and $R_2 = (X_2, Y_2, Z)$ }
    \Ensure {$(R_3, \overline R_3)\mspace{5mu} = \mspace{5mu}ZADDC_{(X,Y)}(R_1, R_2)$$\mspace{10mu}$where $R_3= R_1 + R_2=
(X_3, Y_3, Z_3)$ and $\overline R_3 =R_1 - R_2= (\overline{X_3},\overline {Y_3}, Z_3)$ }\\
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase A:}}
%   $z := 0, R_1 := x$\;
%   $R_2 := u_2$\; 
%   
%   \tcc{\textbf{Phase B:}}
$B=(X_1-X_2)^2$;  
    $E_1 =X_1 U; E_2 = X_2 U$; $C =(Y_1 - Y_2)^2$;\\
      $D =Y_1 (E_1 - E_2)$; $X_3=C - V_1 - V_2$;
      $Y_3=(Y_1 - Y_2)(E_1 - X_3 ) - D$; \\
     $\overline{C} = (Y1 + Y2)^2$;  $\overline{X_3}=  \overline{C} - E_1 - E_2$; $\overline{Y_3} = (Y_1 + Y_2)(E_1 - \overline{X_3} ) - D$;\\
    
    \Return{($R_3,\overline R_3$)}\;
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]